# How to configure Flink cluster for logging via web ui?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink cluster set up and I'd like to be able to view the logs and stdout for the JobManager and TaskManagers.  When I go to the web ui, I see the following error messages on the respective tabs:

```
JobManager:
    Logs
        (log file unavailable)
    Stdout
        (stdout file unavailable)

TaskManager
    Logs
        Fetching TaskManager log failed.
    Stdout
        Fetching TaskManager log failed.
```

I can see that there are some config parameters that could be set, notably `taskmanager.log.path`, `job manager.web.log.path` and `env.log.dir`.  However, there is no mention of whether these should be network accessible paths or are they local paths etc.

What do I need to do to be able to view task manager and job manager logs?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?
How did you deploy Flink? Did you check if the log files exist on the machines (in the `log/` directory) and if they exist, if they contain any errors?

Comment: Centos7, deployed via Kubernetes.  When I go to the container running the task manager running a job, I see nothing inside the `log` directory where Flink was installed (which for me is `/opt/flink/log`).  However, I do see Flink logs from the container console.  Flink appears to be running ok (both cluster and job), from what I can see.

Comment: Ah, okay. I think the "problem" is that the docker images are not logging to the log file, but to standard out.
Maybe you can adopt the log4j properties to log to a file as well?

Comment: Same problem with current Docker image (flink 1.5), have you solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've found is that if you are running the official Flink docker container (https://hub.docker.com/_/flink), it by default spits everything to the console (i.e docker best practice generally speaking I guess). Thus, the log4j config that seems relevant to adjust is `/opt/flink/conf/log4j-console.properties`. This is the case for both `jobamanger(s)` and `taskmanager(s)`.

Thus I've configured that file to not just spit to console but also to file (a rolling one in my case):

*log4j-console.properties:*

```
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console, file
    # Uncomment this if you want to _only_ change Flink's logging
    #log4j.logger.org.apache.flink=INFO
    # The following lines keep the log level of common libraries/connectors on
    # log level INFO. The root logger does not override this. You have to manually
    # change the log levels here.
    log4j.logger.akka=INFO
    log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO
    log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=INFO
    log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO
    # Log all infos to the console
    log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n
    # Log all INFOs to the given rolling file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.file=/opt/flink/log/output.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5
    log4j.appender.file.append=true
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n
    # Suppress the irrelevant (wrong) warnings from the Netty channel handler
    log4j.logger.org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline=ERROR, console, file
```

The above combined with the `flink-conf.yaml` below was able to display the jobmanager's log in the Jobmanager's Log Tab, and display the taksmanager's log in the Taskmanager's Log Tab.

*flink-conf.yaml:*

```
    # General configuration
    taskmanager.data.port: 6121
    taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122
    jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
    blob.server.port: 6124
    query.server.port: 6125
    jobmanager.rpc.address: <your location>
    jobmanager.heap.size: 1024m
    taskmanager.heap.size: 1024m
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1
    web.log.path: /opt/flink/log/output.log
    taskmanager.log.path: /opt/flink/log/output.log
```

*NOTE:* I'm on Flink 1.8.0, running a small cluster in Kubernetes (i.e. separate pods for the jobmanager and taskmanagers)

Answer (score 0):

The JobManager web UI requests the TaskManager logs remotely, so these don't have to reside on a shared file system. The JobManager logs, on the other hand, appear to get read from the local file system.

With the default log4j.properties, all log files get *written* to the path specified by the `log.file` property. With the default Flink start script, the directory in this property is controlled by the `env.log.dir` config option (through the `FLINK_LOG_DIR` variable).

`taskmanager.log.path` only appears to get used when logs are *requested* from a TaskManager by the JobManager. However, there is a fallback to `log.file` if it's unset, which should cause the right directory to get used automatically. Similarly, `jobmanager.web.log.path` doesn't even get used at all when `log.file` is set.

Therefore, I don't think `taskmanager.log.path` and `jobmanager.web.log.path` are relevant for a production deployment and can't tell how they're supposed to be used (see [my corresponding Flink bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7503)). You may set `env.log.dir` to control the log file location, which in principle should also work with the web UI.

Comment: I'm wondering where to set the env.log.dir. I tried to set it in flink-conf.yaml: /opt/flink/log . but it seems to be ignored completely. But when i add jobmanager.web.log.path: /opt/flink/log/output.log, then the webui will display at least the log.

Comment: @buddy `env.log.dir` is [not read from the YAML config](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.4.0/flink-dist/src/main/flink-bin/bin/config.sh#L279) if the `FLINK_LOG_DIR` environment variable is set, so you may check whether that is defined in your environment. Depending on how exactly you start Flink, it could e.g. be explicitly set in a start script.