# How to view task logs in flink web ui?

Tags: log4j2, apache-flink

I can view the task manager's logs from web ui:

[image]

But suppose I submit a job, and use log4j2 to write some logs to a specific file, can I make some configurations so I can view the logs from web ui?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/55871120/1806782

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script :

```
$FLINK_HOME/bin/flink
```

You will find these 2 lines:

```
log=$FLINK_LOG_DIR/flink-$FLINK_IDENT_STRING-client-$HOSTNAME.log
log_setting=(-Dlog.file="$log" -Dlog4j.configuration=file:"$FLINK_CONF_DIR"/log4j-cli.properties -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:"$FLINK_CONF_DIR"/logback.xml)
```

Either you configure log4j to store the logs in flink path, i.e: `$FLINK_HOME/log`, or modify `$FLINK_HOME/bin/flink` script by adding log4j logs path location.

Hope it helps :) !